# Trouble understanding tensorflow shuffle_batch enqueue_many=False

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am reading the Tensorflow documentation and the code for the Cifar10 example.  This bit is currently racking my brain:

```
# Creates batches of 32 images and 32 labels.
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [single_image, single_label],
  batch_size=32,
  num_threads=4,
  capacity=50000,
  min_after_dequeue=10000)
```

We are passing in a single image, and somehow a batch of images results?? What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `single_image` or `single_label` tensor would usually refer to an operation that retrieves the next value from a queue. To create a batch, it would then for example retrieve the batch size (e.g. 32) of values from those tensors if it wasn't shuffled. In the case where it is shuffled it will retrieve between `min_after_dequeue` and `capacity` values.

Note that the now suggested approach is to use the [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) instead. Although it will work in a very similar way there too.